# How to get a value from a table tr td

Tags: javascript, python, jquery

I have this code on my html file

```
{% for dimension in dimension_list %}
<tr>
  <td>{{dimension.title}}</td>
  <td>{{dimension.description}}</td>
  <div class="button-group">
    <td><button type="button" class="delete btn" id="btn-confirm-del" ><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button></td>
  </div>
</tr>       
{% endfor %}
```

How to get the value of `dimension.title` when the user clicks on the button `#btn-confirm-del`?

I want to show it on a modal.

Comment: Ids have to be _unique_

Comment: so I can do it <td id="{{dimension.id}}">{{dimension.title}}</td>

Comment: Or use classes.

Comment: but how can I get this value using jquery?

Comment: This is also invalid markup.  The div is not in a td.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use closest method in jquery

```js
$('.delete').on('click', function(){
 var dTitle = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first-child').text()
  alert(dTitle);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <td>{{dimension.title}}</td>
  <td>{{dimension.description}}</td>
  <td>
  <div class="button-group">
    <button type="button" class="delete btn" >delete<i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
  </div>
 </td>
  
</tr>  

<tr>
  <td>{{dimension.title}}</td>
  <td>{{dimension.description}}</td>
  <td>
  <div class="button-group">
    <button type="button" class="delete btn" >delete<i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
  </div>
 </td>
  
</tr>  

</table>
```

i hope this will help you

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following:

```
$('.btn.delete').on('click', function(event){
     $(event.currentTarget).closest('tr').children('td').first().text();
});
```

This gets the nearest `<tr>` to the button and then gets the value from inside the first `<td>`

Comment: Don't repeat ids.  This has already been said.  Use a class, and you can use the class selector in the place of the id selector

Answer (score 1):

To escape from playing with `id`s within a loop, I prefer the following *(in native JS)*;

Change the button to :

```
<button type="button" class="delete btn"  onclick="delete(event)"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
```

Catch that button in the JS part as following :

```
function delete(event) {
 console.log(
   (event.currentTarget)
   .parentElement
   .parentElement
   .parentElement
   .childNodes[0]
   .innerHTML)
}
```

Comment: Unless you are using a framework like react/vue/angular, it's generally frowned upon from performing inline binding.  Inline binding does not respect the idea of separation of concerns.  It is more appropriate to use logical bindings.

Comment: @Taplar , thanks for the info, indeed am coming from an angular background.

Comment: No worries.  Though I should say that with react/vue/angular, it may look like you are doing inline bindings, however I would wager that they are actually doing logical bindings behind the scenes, because the templating that you give your directives isn't pure html.  The templates get processed and I wouldn't be surprised if it didn't make the logical bindings for you.

Answer (score 1):

you can use something like this  :

```
{% for dimension in dimension_list %}
<tr>
  <td id="{{dimension.id}}">{{dimension.title}}</td>
  <td>{{dimension.description}}</td>
  <div class="button-group">
    <td><button type="button" class="delete btn" onclick="get_title(\'' +{{dimension.id}}+ '\',\'' +{{dimension.title}}+ '\');"  ><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button></td>
  </div>
</tr>       
{% endfor %}
```

JS part:

```
function get_title(id,title){
  var title = $("#"+id).text();
  console.log(title);
}
```